# How do you turn off "precompiled header", default "checked" MS VS

Tags: visual-studio, precompiled-headers

When I make a new project, the precomp header defaults on.  How do I make it default off?

Comment: You need to change the default project template - but it's been a while since I did C++ so I'm not sure where/how you do this with the latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the AppSettings.htm file in the vc\vcwizards\appwiz\generic\application\html\xxxx subdirectory of the VS install directory.  xxxx is your language id, it is 1033 for English.  Make a copy of the file and open it in a text editor.  Locate the InitControls javascript function.  Add the line

```
 PRE_COMPILED_HEADER.checked = false;
```

to the if() statement that checks CONSOLE_APP.checked.  Further tweak as needed, I haven't otherwise checked this.